# Does having binaries with mismatched optimization levels (-O3, -O2, -O1, -O0) cause stability issues?

Tags: c++, interop, compiler-optimization, abi

Does having binaries with mismatched optimization levels (-O3, -O2, -O1, -O0) cause stability issues? For example, if app.exe is -O2, and libapp.so is -O3, or app.o with -O2 and libxyz.a with -O3?

Comment: Shouldn't do. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: It could seemingly do that if you have UB in your code. Also if your compiler has a bug in the optimization part (but those are typically 'quite rare')

Comment: Imagine linking against multiple 3rd-party libraries that were compiled with different optimisation levels. If doing this caused stability issues, there would most likely be only one optimisation level because otherwise all code everywhere would be completely broken.

Comment: @AlanBirtles How can you say that it can't cause issues, in all and every case?

Comment: I've added some tags. I'm not sure "compiler-construction" is appropriate here, but I've left it. Interesting question, in any case!

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to test an -O0 build.  Except in the kind of product that distinguishes between a "debug" and "release" configuration.  They shall not be named.  The debug configuration has a lot of extra checks in the CRT and the C++ library to diagnose UB, mixing different build versions of those libraries in one program does not work well.

Comment: @curiousguy all i said was `shouldn't do` and asked if there was a specific problem, no where did i say `in all and every case`. I could easily write a library with a different ABI depending on optimisation level but otherwise on Linux (based on the example given using .so files) optimisation level wouldn't normally the ABI

Comment: It's not even unheard of to have different optimization levels per _function_.

Answer (score 0):

In general no, having mismatched optimisation levels does not cause stability issues.

In theory, a particularly badly written library could change its binary interface based on an implementation defined pre-processor macro that is defined based on optimisation level in which case there could be a problem.

This is not very common in my experience. A more common problem is the `NDEBUG` macro (and similar).

Comment: Is there a guarantee that optimization level can't change code behavior?

Comment: @curiousguy The C++ standard specifies how the program behaves in certain cases. A language implementation must not change any observable part of that behaviour or else it will not conform to the standard. Some behaviours outside of those cases are implementation defined, of which the standard makes no guarantees.

Comment: Pretty much all real world programs use implementation defined behavior at so point...

Answer (score 0):

Optimization level alone cannot affect it but frequently optimization level is coupled with some MACROS that affect build resulting in ABI issues. For instance, in MSVC a dll built in release mode will likely cause crash if it is linked to debug mode application if it accepts a reference to `std::string` as input for some function (not that one should have a `std::string` or reference to it as input in a shared library).

Also if the library and application are built with different compilers/options there might be some ABI issues if library's interface uses any complex classes. You should check compilers documentation for that info.

Also, if there is a bug in the code then optimization level might change the behaviour of the bug leading to some odd inconsistencies between optimization levels.

Comment: Having a `std::string` in a private DLL of your own application is fine. The problem is with _shared libraries_ that are truly shared between applications, possibly built with different compilers. That's not just memory; what character set does everyone use? Windows has `BSTR` which sidesteps that problem.

Comment: @MSalters `std::string` is built around ASCII (or UTF8 in some cases) characters so that's fine but when forwarding it to a dll the versions of `std::string` might differ causing serious issues.